# Difference between two similar algorithms of 3Sum?

Tags: java, algorithm

I found the 3Sum problem on http://www.leetcode.com/onlinejudge which goes like below:

Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Note:
    Elements in a triplet (a,b,c) must be in non-descending order. (ie, a ≤ b ≤ c)
    The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

```
For example, given array S = {-1 0 1 2 -1 -4},

A solution set is:
(-1, 0, 1)
(-1, -1, 2)
```

I went through the site and found this suggested solution:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> threeSum(int[] num) {
    Arrays.sort(num);
    HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> lstSoln = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    ArrayList<Integer> tempArr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        int k = num.length - 1;
        while (j < k) {
            int sum3 = num[i] + num[j] + num[k];
            if (sum3 < 0) {
                j++;
            } else if (sum3 > 0) {
                k--;
            } else {
                tempArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                Collections.addAll(tempArr, num[i], num[j], num[k]);
                lstSoln.add(tempArr);
                j++;
                k--;
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(lstSoln);
}
```

As you can see, this takes every number and then follows with two number after the current index. So, it is pretty clear that once the first positive number is reached, we are just doing useless looping and we are not going to find any triplet adding to 0. So I modified the solution and added a condition after `for`

```
if (num[i] > 0)
    break;
```

Effectively this should lower the number of times the for loop runs and hence reduce the time taken to find the solution. This I even checked by adding a counter and incrementing it at every `if()`. Every time the `COUNTER` for my solution is less than the counter for suggested solution.

But still, when I enter my modified solution at there checking page, it either causes time out error or the time taken is showed to be more than the unmodified version! I want to know what's wrong with my modification?

Comment: Is it possible that your solution can execute more test cases before being judged Time Limit Exceeded, therefore showing a higher value?  Yours is definitely better.  And FYI, 3SUM has a lower bound of O(n^2), if we don't take the 32-bit int limit into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see anything wrong with your solution, I tried both the solutions on my local and the one with added if condition runs faster. I checked the time difference using System.nanotime(). You might be facing timeout errors on there solution checking page because of network issues.

Comment: At first even I thought the same, but then, I checked multiple times with modified and unmodified version and more or less the results were same. According to them, the unmodified one runs faster. Even in my PC using `System.nanoTime()` it's quite obvious that mine should have been faster.